# How do I bake to only selected faces?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I have a UV map where some faces overlap and some don't. The overlapping faces are overlapped on purpose.

Now, I want to do an occlusion bake on the non overlapping faces, but it seems to always bake the whole object.

Is there a way to only bake the faces I have selected?

Comment: you could separate the pieces to bake, then rejoin them after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place the unwanted faces outside the UV map before baking.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any ways you can bake just certain faces.  But, you can bake the entire object and create a separate material for the baked part.  Then assign it to just the faces you want baked and leave the other faces with their materials, or give them a separate bake.

Comment: Well, no is the direct and right answer to my question.  You cant bake only selected faces. But the solution was very simple...